# How do I solve $3xy=4xz=5yz$ ${x+y \over x-z}=?$

Tags: prime-numbers

$3xy=4xz=5yz$

$ {x+y \over x-z}=?$

The answer is ${9 \over 2}$

But how to solve?

I am preparing for exam.

> This question comes from metropol mathematics 1 testbook

Comment: $\frac{x+y}{x-z}$ isn't a statement

Comment: The arrow means "implies that". The fraction you posted, what does it means?

Comment: @Ripi2 edited question

Comment: Good. Use the hint (substitute in the fraction) in Fareed's answer.

Comment: Find the values of x,y,z by solving a system of equations on the left side of the arrow. Then plug the values into the expression on the right side of the arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x=\frac{5y}{4}$ and $z=\frac{3y}{4}$

Does this help?

Comment: The answer is ${9 \over 2}$

Comment: @black Assume $y \neq 0$ and use those $2$ values in the fraction, remove the common factor of $y$ in the numerator & denominator, then what do you get after you otherwise simplify the result?

Comment: @JohnOmielan I get 4

Comment: @black You must've made a mistake. Note $x + y = \frac{5y}{4} + \frac{4y}{4} = \left(\frac{9}{4}\right)y$ and $x - z = \frac{5y}{4} - \frac{3y}{4} = \left(\frac{2}{4}\right)y$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose

$$3xy=4xz=5yz$$

then

$$3xy=4xz \implies y=\frac{4z}{3}=\frac{4x}{5}$$ 
$$4xz=5yz \implies x=\frac{5y}{4}=\frac{5z}{3}$$
$$3xy=5yz \implies z=\frac{3x}{5}=\frac{3y}{4}$$

and

$$x+y=x+\frac{4x}{5}=\frac{9x}{5}$$
$$x-z=x-\frac{3x}{5}=\frac{2x}{5}$$

so provided $x\neq 0$

$$\frac{x+y}{x-z}={\frac{45x}{10x}}=\frac{9}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is no single answer without additional restrictions on $x,y,z$. First we notice that if a constant in each of the three expressions is considered a missing variable, we quickly get a solution $z=3,y=4,x=5$, then the answer would be $(x+y)/(x-z)=9/2.$ But notice that $x=1,y=0,z=0$ is also a solution, but then $(x+y)/(x-z)=1$.